# posting values with jquery and retriving it on php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello i have a question about posting a value with jquery from page test.php to fetch.php. i want to recall the post with a $_post function, but i can't get it to work and i cannot figuring out why.

please can someone else help me with this problem

this is the **fetch.php**

```
if(empty($_GET['hash'])){
    $_GET['hash'] = '';
}
echo $_GET['hash'];
```

this is the **test.php** page

```
    <div id="results">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#results" ).load( "/libaries/pagination/fetch.php"); //load initial records
        //executes code below when user click on pagination links
        $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
            var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
            var hash = location.hash;

            $("#results").load("/libaries/pagination/fetch.php",{"page":page},{"hash":hash}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
                $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: side note: for your `fetch.php`, it's rare to set a value to `$_GET`; always get results from `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`. And where is `fetch_pages.php` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is incorrect, you only pass one data object with as many properties as you need in it as 2nd argument of `load`.

Proper structure would be:

```
$("#results").load("/libaries/pagination/fetch.php",{"page":page,"hash":hash}, function(){
    // new html exists, can run any manipulation code needed here
});
```

Note that when passing an object as data the request will be a POST

Reference: [load() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)